# drag and drop add many items at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have to create objects (as if they were bar tables) that are drag and drop. When I use the first one with the "original" function it works fine. Then the program starts with the "table" number 10, when I click on the button "create table", I should create another button, I already create the second id, but I "blocked" the two and should be able to move both or all of them that I want to believe. here my code.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#draggable").draggable({
            containment: "parent"
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="contenedor" id="sector">
    <div id="draggable" class="mesas ui-widget-content">
        <p class="numMesa">10</p>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Crear mesa" class="menu" id="creador"> 
<div class="contenedor" id="sector">
    <div id="draggable" class="mesas ui-widget-content">
        <p class="numMesa">10</p>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Crear mesa" class="menu" id="creador"> 

<div class="contenedor" id="sector">
    <div id="draggable" class="mesas ui-widget-content">
        <p class="numMesa">10</p>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Crear mesa" class="menu" id="creador"> </body>
<script>
$("#creador").on("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("sector").innerHTML = '<div id="draggable" class="mesas ui-widget-content"><p class="numMesa">10</p></div>';
});
```